# JQuery - option selected not allowing change

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a JQuery dynamically created form which I need to be able to edit and look for a change in an option, but the code below only picks up the selected value because the second line of code sets the default value as defined by what was already selected, but on changing the drop-down, no matter what I select it always keeps the original value - and I presume because it's been selected by the second line, how do I break this on changing the option text (I have no values, just text).

```
$('#msgBox4').html($('#msgBox4').html() + '<div class="table-row"><div class="table-col-l">Type:</div><div class="table-col-r"><select id="type2" required="required"><option selected value="" disabled> -- select an option -- </option><option>Holiday</option><option>Sick</option><option>Working Off Site</option></select></div></div>')
$("#type2 > option:contains('"+calEvent.description+"')").attr("selected", "selected");
Reason = $( "#type2 option:selected" ).text();
```

So the variable Reason always returns the originally selected result, not whatever I change it to.

Comment: are you clearing the selection of all other items first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shows the selected option text in a message box:

```
$("#msgBox4").on("change", "#type2", function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/951fya67/)

Comment: That code works perfectly, thank you - I didn't realise you could reference in that way (I wasn't sure how you'd reference `msgBox4` which is dynamically created), but inserting that code and adding the `Reason` variable and setting it to `$(this).val()` works like a charm.

Comment: @Hyperjase It is actually called delegated events. If you defined the event trigger directly on `#type2`, which is a generated element, the event would not work. Therefore you have to apply the event on an existing element and then specify which item to listen for and on which event. And am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Before you try this code I would like to tell you something that please add value in option whatever you want.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#msgBox4').html($('#msgBox4').html() + '<div class="table-row"><div class="table-col-l">Type:</div><div class="table-col-r"><select id="type2" required="required"><option selected value="" disabled> -- select an option -- </option><option value="Holiday">Holiday</option><option value="Sick">Sick</option><option value="Working Off Site">Working Off Site</option></select></div></div>');


$("#type2").on('change',function(){
var Reason = $("#type2").val();
alert(Reason);
 //and your other actions 
});

});
```

Thank you ['}

Comment: I understand that adding a `value` option adds the ability to create different values to the labels given but I chose not to use `value` because I was able to reference it via `.text()` so the label was enough of a description for my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Found a sightly better way of doing it (as I found that if the drop-down wasn't changed it resulted it `Reason` being `undefined` so after a quick search I found this, adapted it and it works perfectly now, just checks when the `dialog` is closed and get the current option text.

```
$( "#msgBox4" ).bind( "dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
    Reason = $('#type2').val();
});
```